# Doctrine2 - Doctrine generating query with associated entity - InvalidFieldNameException

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

Yep, the title suggests: Doctrine is looking for a fieldname that's not there. That's both true and not true at the same time, though I cannot figure out how to fix it.

The full error:

> **File**: D:\path\to\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:71
>
> **Message**: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT id_2
>   FROM (SELECT p0_.name AS name_0, p0_.code AS code_1, p0_.id AS id_2
>   FROM product_statuses p0_) dctrn_result ORDER BY p0_.language_id ASC, name_0 ASC LIMIT 25
>   OFFSET 0':
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'p0_.language_id' in 'order clause'

The query the error is caused by (from error above):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_2
FROM (
       SELECT p0_.name AS name_0, p0_.code AS code_1, p0_.id AS id_2
       FROM product_statuses p0_
     ) dctrn_result
ORDER BY p0_.language_id ASC, name_0 ASC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Clearly, that query is not going to work. The `ORDER BY` should be in the sub-query, or else it should replace `p0_` in the ORDER BY with `dctrn_result` and also get the `language_id` column in the sub-query to be returned.

The query is build using the QueryBuilder in the indexAction of a Controller in Zend Framework. All is very normal and the same function works perfectly fine when using a the `addOrderBy()` function for a single `ORDER BY` statement. In this instance I wish to use 2, first by language, then by name. But the above happens.

If someone knows a full solution to this (or maybe it's a bug?), that would be nice. Else a hint in the right direction to help me solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Below additional information - Entity and `indexAction()`**

**ProductStatus.php - Entity** - Note the presence of `language_id` column

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_statuses")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Hzw\Product\Repository\ProductStatusRepository")
 */
class ProductStatus extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @var Language
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hzw\Country\Entity\Language")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $language;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|Product[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Hzw\Product\Entity\Product", mappedBy="status")
     */
    protected $products;

    [Getters/Setters]
}
```

**IndexAction** - Removed parts not directly related to QueryBuilder. Added in comments showing params as they are.

```
    /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select($asParam)              // 'pro'
        ->from($emEntity, $asParam);   // Hzw\Product\Entity\ProductStatus, 'pro'

    if (count($queryParams) > 0 && !is_null($query)) {
        // [...] creates WHERE statement, unused in this instance
    }

    if (isset($orderBy)) {  
        if (is_array($orderBy)) { 

            // !!! This else is executed !!!   <-----
            if (is_array($orderDirection)) { // 'ASC'
                // [...] other code
            } else {
                // $orderBy = ['language', 'name'], $orderDirection = 'ASC'

                foreach ($orderBy as $orderParam) {
                    $qb->addOrderBy($asParam . '.' . $orderParam, $orderDirection);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // This works fine. A single $orderBy with a single $orderDirection
            $qb->addOrderBy($asParam . '.' . $orderBy, $orderDirection);
        }
    }
```

================================================

**UPDATE: I found the problem**

The above issue is not caused by incorrect mapping or a possible bug. It's that the `QueryBuilder` does not automatically handle associations between entities when creating queries.

My expectation was that when an entity, such as ProductStatus above, contains the id's of the relation (i.e. `language_id` column), that it would be possible to use those properties in the QueryBuilder without issues.

Please see my own answer below how I fixed my functionality to be able to have a default handling of a single level of nesting (i.e. ProducStatus#language == Language, be able to use `language.name` as `ORDER BY` identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after more searching around and digging into how and where this goes wrong, I found out that Doctrine does not handle relation type properties of entities during the generation of queries; or maybe does not default to using say, the primary key of an entity if nothing is specified.

In the use case of my question above, the `language` property is of a `@ORM\ManyToOne` association to the `Language` entity.

My use case calls for the ability to handle at lease one level of relations for default actions. So after I realized that this is not handled automatically (or with modifications such as `language.id` or `language.name` as identifiers) I decided to write a little function for it.

```
/**
 * Adds order by parameters to QueryBuilder. 
 * 
 * Supports single level nesting of associations. For example:
 * 
 * Entity Product
 * product#name
 * product#language.name
 * 
 * Language being associated entity, but must be ordered by name. 
 * 
 * @param QueryBuilder  $qb
 * @param string        $tableKey - short alias (e.g. 'tab' with 'table AS tab') used for the starting table
 * @param string|array  $orderBy - string for single orderBy, array for multiple
 * @param string|array  $orderDirection - string for single orderDirection (ASC default), array for multiple. Must be same count as $orderBy.
 */
public function createOrderBy(QueryBuilder $qb, $tableKey, $orderBy, $orderDirection = 'ASC')
{
    if (!is_array($orderBy)) {
        $orderBy = [$orderBy];
    }

    if (!is_array($orderDirection)) {
        $orderDirection = [$orderDirection];
    }

    // $orderDirection is an array. We check if it's of equal length with $orderBy, else throw an error.
    if (count($orderBy) !== count($orderDirection)) {

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
            $this->getTranslator()->translate(
                'If you specify both OrderBy and OrderDirection as arrays, they should be of equal length.'
            )
        );
    }

    $queryKeys = [$tableKey];

    foreach ($orderBy as $key => $orderParam) {
        if (strpos($orderParam, '.')) {
            if (substr_count($orderParam, '.') === 1) {
                list($entity, $property) = explode('.', $orderParam);
                $shortName = strtolower(substr($entity, 0, 3)); // Might not be unique...
                $shortKey = $shortName . '_' . (count($queryKeys) + 1); // Now it's unique, use $shortKey when continuing
                $queryKeys[] = $shortKey;
                $shortName = strtolower(substr($entity, 0, 3));
                $qb->join($tableKey . '.' . $entity, $shortName, Join::WITH);

                $qb->addOrderBy($shortName . '.' . $property, $orderDirection[$key]);
            } else {

                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                    $this->getTranslator()->translate(
                        'Only single join statements are supported. Please write a custom function for deeper nesting.'
                    )
                );
            }
        } else {
            $qb->addOrderBy($tableKey . '.' . $orderParam, $orderDirection[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

It by no means supports everything the `QueryBuilder` offers and is definitely not a final solution. But it gives a starting point and solid "default functionality" for an abstract function.